# Bean property 'truck' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, setter, getter

Делаю приложение на Spring Boot с Thymeleaf и PostgreSQL. При попытке обратиться в Thymeleaf'е к свойству сущности получаю ошибку:

```
2023-09-18T14:48:38.476+03:00 ERROR 11172 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring6.processor.SpringSelectFieldTagProcessor' (template: "trucks" - line 46, col 17)] with root cause

org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'truck' of bean class [com.terentyev.transportation.entities.Truck]: Bean property 'truck' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
```

В описании ошибки и в интернете пишут, что проблема в неправильных getter'ах и setter'ах или имени переменной, но их я проверял, тем более геттеры и сеттеры сгенерированы IDE'шкой. Название свойства вроде тоже правильное. В чем ошибка? Пробовал писать `truck.isTrailer` и `isTrailer()` - не работает.

Представление (ошибка в 46 строке, где `<td><select th:field="*{isTrailer}">`):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<style>
   table { 
    width: 100%; 
    border: 4px double black; 
    border-collapse: collapse; 
   }
   th { 
    text-align: left; 
    background: #ccc; 
    padding: 5px; 
    border: 1px solid black; 
   }
   td { 
    padding: 5px; 
    border: 1px solid black; 
   }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div><form th:method="POST" th:action="@{/boss/trucks}">
        <select th:name="*{searchForTrailers}">
            <option th:value="false">Машины</option>
            <option th:value="true">Прицепы</option>
        </select>
        
    </form></div>
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>Марка</td>
            <td>Модель</td>
            <td>Номер</td>          
            <td>Тип</td>
            </tr>
            <tr><form th:method="POST" th:action="@{/boss/addtruck}" th:object="${truck}">
                <td><input type="submit" value="Добавить"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" th:field="*{make}" placeholder="Марка"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" th:field="*{model}" placeholder="Модель"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" th:field="*{number}" placeholder="Номер"/></td>
                <td><select th:field="*{isTrailer}">
                    <option th:value="false">Машина</option>
                    <option th:value="true">Прицеп</option>
                </select></td>
                <td th:if="${truck.isTrailer}">
                    <select th:each="type : ${trailerTypes}">
                        <option th:value="${type}" th:text="${type.name}"></option>
                        <option th:action="@{/addtrailertype}">Добавить</option>
                        </select></td></form></tr>
            <tr th:each="truck : ${trucks}">
                <td th:text="${truck.id}"></td>
                <td th:text="${truck.make}"></td>
                <td th:text="${truck.model}"></td>
                <td th:text="${truck.number}"></td>
                <td th:if="${truck.isTrailer}" th:text="${truck.type}"></td>
                </tr>
        </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Сущность:

```
package com.terentyev.transportation.entities;

import java.util.List;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToOne;
import jakarta.persistence.OneToMany;
import jakarta.persistence.OneToOne;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "trucks")
public class Truck {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;    
    private boolean isTrailer;
    private String make;
    @ManyToOne
    private Type type;
    private String model;
    private String number;
    
    public Truck(){}
    
    

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }



    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }



    public boolean isTrailer() {
        return isTrailer;
    }



    public void setTrailer(boolean isTrailer) {
        this.isTrailer = isTrailer;
    }



    public String getMake() {
        return make;
    }



    public void setMake(String make) {
        this.make = make;
    }



    public Type getType() {
        return type;
    }



    public void setType(Type type) {
        this.type = type;
    }



    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }



    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }



    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }



    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }



    @Entity
    @Table(name = "trailer_types")
    public static class Type {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;
        private String name;
        @OneToMany
        private List<Truck> trucks;
        //private List<Type> types;
        
        public Type(){}

        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public List<Truck> getTrucks() {
            return trucks;
        }

        public void setTrucks(List<Truck> trucks) {
            this.trucks = trucks;
        }           
        
        
    }
}
```

UPD Только сейчас заметил, что скопировал сюда не ту ошибку. Это я экспериментировал с указанием переменной. В общем выдавалась та же самая ошибка, только вместо `truck` было указано `isTrailer`. Да и в целом проблема решена.

Comment: Решил проблему. Пришлось переименовать поле `isTrailer` в просто `trailer` и по новой сгенерировать геттер и сеттер к нему. Видимо `Thymeleaf` ищет геттеры по какому-то иному названию, нежели сгенерированы средой разработки `Eclipse`.